# Object properties lowercased when reading as JSONObject

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I have the following problem. I'm reading a list of records from my MySQL database with Hibernate template, and then I need to modify the structure so I'm JSONObject and JSONArray (using I guess the official library : http://www.json.org/java/). If I'm using the List as a server response, records fields are properly named (thanks to @JsonProperty annotation used). But if I'm trying to create a JSONObject out of this List element, I'm getting all my fields starting with small letter, which breaks my UI.

This is my 'Task' model used :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name="tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
    private String Name;


    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

and here's the code used for getting records from the DB (stripped of all the unnecessary parts):

```
public List<Task> getEvents() {

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Task.class);

    return hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
}    

private static JSONArray read() throws JSONException{
    List<Task> list = getEvents();
    Iterator<Task> listIterator = list.iterator();
    JSONArray ret = new JSONArray();
    String parentId;

    while(listIterator.hasNext()){
        Task task = listIterator.next();
        JSONObject taskJSON = new JSONObject(task);
        ret.put(taskJSON);
    }
}
```

As you can see in my server response, all fields names start with small letter :
`{"id":18,"name":"Release"}`

Any ideas how to override this ?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to get JSON like this : {"Id": 18, "Name": "Release"}. I can't use the List because it's flat and I need a Tree, that's why I'm using the JSON structures to achieve this.

Comment: Why are you returning a JSONArray -- it is neither the final string output nor does it offer the type safety of a POJO? Are you aware of the `ObjectMapper` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is overannotated, and breaks Java code conventions.

The minimum required is as follows. Everything else you've added is done by default.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private int id;


    @Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

To serialise your class all you should need is the `ObjectMapper` class

```
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(getEvents());
```

The output of which should look like:

```
[{"Id":18,"Name":"Build"}, {"Id":19,"Name":"Release"}]
```

I would discourage using capitalised property names if possible as it goes against general code conventions.

Comment: Unfortunately there is an app on the fronted that can't be rewritten and needs this data to be formatted in a strict way.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON.org API is intended for very simple serialization/deserialization, it can't do what your looking for. Having said that, the majority of your annotations are actually from Jackson, which ***can*** do what your trying to accomplish.

You already have the POJOs properly annotated for Jackson, so return a JSON string conforming to them, serialize using an [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html):

```
final List<Task> list = getEvents();
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```